# MODX mxCalendar XML feed

Tags: xml, calendar, feed, modx, modx-revolution

I am using mxCalendar in MODX and I would like to create an custom XML feed for my calendar as mxcalendar should support XML feed.

In XML feed tab I set one test feed to local .xml file with this test feed:

```
<calendar>
<event>
    <id>2</id>
    <title>test3</title>
    <description>Test description</description>
    <categoryid>1</categoryid>
    <startdate>1355906700</startdate>
    <enddate>1355903100</enddate>
</event>
```

I dont realy know how my feed should look like, because this is my first atempt to create one, so I need some help. I just went to database and exported one event in xml and change some ind is not working.

Have any one tried adding custom feed to mxcalendar in modx and that could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
&displayType=`list`
```

in snippet call and modify `tplListItem, tplListHeading, tplListWrap` to make the right view

Comment: But I don't get any events into mxCalendar manager, or is this how it works?

Comment: it's about how to make output as xml

Comment: i tried with just placeholders in a chunk like [[+id]] but i get this error >>This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.<< Should i put something else in chunks?

Comment: ok I got it running.. but it does not reed xml from the feed but from resource. Is there a way to acheve that. And that events would apear in calendar. Thanks!